# I have an error to read privateKey.pem file because of libeay32.dll : module was built without symbols

Tags: c++, openssl, rsa

```
FILE *fp = fopen(private_key_file_name, "r");
RSA *rsa = NULL;
rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &rsa, NULL, NULL);
return 0;
```

this is part of my codes. And there is an error

> RSA.exe'(Win32): 'C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\libeay32.dll' is loaded.
>   Module was built without symbols.

Comment: So your question is how to avoid this error?  You want it to be built **with** symbols?

Comment: That just seems like debugger information, not an error...

Comment: I want it to built with symbols... I use openssl 0.9.8.k version and when I run the program, it's just black out and say libeay32.dll is built without symbols. I think this is the reason why my program is not working.